# Change size of logo

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to make my logo in the upper left corner bigger than it is: [My site](https://mimsi.dk/).
I can change the `width` on this class, but the logo is getting quite blurry. The logo I uploaded is `512*512px`, but for some reason the logo is only `40*40px` on the site, and I cannot make it bigger than 40px;

Does anybody have an idea how I can make the logo fx. `100*100px`?

On the URL to the picture there has been for some reason set 40px at the end:

https://mimsi.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Webstedsikon-40x40.png

I can change that to:

https://mimsi.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Webstedsikon-100x100.png

Which is the size of the logo that should be on the page.

The CSS on the image is this:

```
#logo img {
    max-height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is not a CSS problem, but a wordpress one. The respective code fragment is probably located in a `header.php`, where the actual `<img>` tag is created.

Comment: So use bigger image to remove blur and actually set height instead of `max-height` (now if image is 40px, it will not increase to 80px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Change the src to https://team-nord.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Webstedsikon-100x100.png, add height: 80px to #logo img. Max-height is to make sure if you zoom in the browser, it can not be too big image, height property is to set the height of the image.

```
#logo img {
    height: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.logo-trans { min-width: 100px; }
```